# document.getElementById().value and document.getElementById().checked not working for IE

Tags: javascript

I tried to assign a new value into the hidden input and checkbox of an input form. It's working fine in Firefox but not in IE (I'm using IE 7). Does anyone know what is wrong with my code?

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="msg" name="msg" value="" style="display:none"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sp" value="100" id="sp_100">
```

Javascript:

```
var Msg="abc";
document.getElementById('msg').value = Msg;
document.getElementById('sp_100').checked = true;
```

Comment: Can't you eliminate the accepted answer? It's just wrong!

Comment: I find the responses with jQuery extremely amateur when questions are asked specifically for Javascript.

Answer (score -9, accepted):

Have a look at [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com/), a cross-browser library that will make your life a lot easier.

```
var msg = 'abc';
$('#msg').val(msg);
$('#sp_100').attr('checked', 'checked');
```

Comment: getElementById and value, checked are supported by every browser under the sun. jQuery is not the answer to everything in the world, and this problem hardly requires it.

Comment: @Paolo - True, but considering the elementary nature of the question, it's worth assuming that the asker is not aware of how much time he might save by using it, so I don't think this really deserves a reprimand.

Comment: @Paolo - true all browsers implement it... but IE (6/7) implements document.getElementById() wrong and jQuery avoids the bugs by heuristics for IE. http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/08/bug-152-getelementbyid-returns.html however in this case I don't believe this method is the issue.

Comment: you don't need some overkill framework to do this. But what you need to do is: to actually check if the function did NOT return null :-)  ......: var o= document.getElementById('msg'); if(o==null) // do something in this special case ; .... else x= o.value;  // :-)

Answer (score 25):

For non-grouped elements, name and id should be same. In this case you gave name as 'sp' and id as 'sp_100'. Don't do that, do it like this:

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" id="msg" name="msg" value="" style="display:none"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="sp" value="100" id="sp">
```

Javascript:

```
var Msg="abc";
document.getElementById('msg').value = Msg;
document.getElementById('sp').checked = true;
```

For more details

please visit : http://www.impressivewebs.com/avoiding-problems-with-javascript-getelementbyid-method-in-internet-explorer-7/

Answer (score 5):

The code you pasted should work... There must be something else we are not seeing here.

[Check this out](http://jsbin.com/ayefe). Working for me fine on IE7. When you submit you will see the variable passed in the URL.

Answer (score 3):

Jin Yong - **[IE has an issue with polluting the global scope](http://webbugtrack.blogspot.com/2007/09/bug-162-global-namespace-pollution-in.html)** with object references to any DOM elements with a "name" or "id" attribute set on the "initial" page load.

Thus you may have issues due to your variable name.

Try this and see if it works.

```
var someOtherName="abc";
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
document.getElementById('msg').value = someOtherName;
document.getElementById('sp_100').checked = true;
```

There is a chance (in your original code) that IE attempts to set the value of the input to a reference to that actual element (ignores the error) but leaves you with no new value.

Keep in mind that in IE6/IE7 case doesn't matter for naming objects. IE believes that "foo" "Foo" and "FOO" are all the same object.