# List of statement IE 10/11 doesn't support anymore

Tags: javascript, asp.net, internet-explorer

Sorry but I have a very generic question and need the experties of the people who have done this type of activity before. There is an old website written in Asp.Net 2.0 with treditional javascrip, Ajex, custom controls and html 4. If we open this in IE 10 or 11 it doesn't work as expected. for example old treditional `document.getElementById` doesn't work in IE 10. There might be many more like this.

I googled but could not found the relevent help about to know what else IE 10/11 are not supporting and we need to replace in code.

Does anybody has such relevent experties to list the statements which doesn't support by IE 10/11 anymore? We need to make it compatible with IE 10/11 without compatibility mode option.

Please provide your feedback.

Comment: `getElementById()` was introduced in IE4, and it's still supported in IE11, sixteen years later...

Comment: Yes, getElementById is working perfactly. I saw something like this in one of the article so and our website is not performing the action of javascript which has getElementById in methods so I posted it without cross verifying it. Now I verified it and seems ok. So the problem is  somewhere else

Comment: You've seen [IE10 Compatibility Changes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh801219%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Comment: Yes I have seen this link before. I have not started any implementation (R&D) in code level so far. Just try to get more and more information to prepare a checklist of change required for whole website (every page need to be validate for that checklist).

Answer (score 1):

IE 10/11 is by far the most compatible browser of all IE browsers. Which version are you porting from? What isn't working specifically? You should look at [caniuse](http://www.caniuse.com) for browser compatibility.

Here are couple of SO threads that might be useful:

[document.getElementByID Not Working in IE 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11877034/document-getelementbyid-not-working-in-ie-8)

[document.getElementById().value and document.getElementById().checked not working for IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/973045/document-getelementbyid-value-and-document-getelementbyid-checked-not-workin)

Comment: Web Site is in Asp.Net 2.0. And page is working fine in IE 9 but not in IE 10.